# Migrating to Snow Leopard messed up my ruby path

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, .profile

Since I've migrated from Leopard to Snow Leopard I get

```
$ ruby script/server 
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2. Please install RubyGems and try again: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org
```

the only way to make it work is:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

So I guess something got broken with my path, here is my ~/.profile file fyi:

```
##
# DELUXE-USR-LOCAL-BIN-INSERT
# (do not remove this comment)
##
echo $PATH | grep -q -s "/usr/local/bin"
if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH
fi

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/local/share/man
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/opt/local/share/info

PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH

export GEMDIR=`gem env gemdir`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: leo - if you change the title, this might just scrape thro without being closed  [edit] -  i see it has been changed :)

Comment: also echo $PATH. it appears that you can clean it up a lot as you wil have /usr/local/bin and /opt/local bin in there a couple of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

install RVM   http://rvm.io/

Problem solved..

There is also number of other similar software: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/help/alt.md

Comment: This is indeed the most hassle-free solution!

Comment: Not only the most hassle-free solution, but it also allows you to use multiple rubies at once (e.g. 1.8.7, 1.9.2 and jruby).

Comment: @Doon: I've installed RVM | Inserted:  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" in my .bash_profile | Tested the whole thing: $ type rvm | head -n1 (return: rvm is a function) | But when I type: "$ rvm install 1.8.7" I got: ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/leonardodarioperna/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p302/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation. (see the make.log here http://pastebin.com/vJ4kVm0U)

Comment: @Doon: BTW I've XCode 3.2.3 (1688), 64bit.

Comment: @Doon: I added [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session. at the end of my ~/.profile as well ...same error.Could it be a 32/64bit issue?

Comment: @Doon: yep, it was a 64bit nightmare, I fixed it adding: rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64" in my ~/.rvmrc

Comment: OSX doesn't have readline installed (it has a different lib). Follow the steps here.  http://niwos.com/2010/03/19/rvm-on-osx-snow-leopard-readline-errors/

Comment: NOW $ ruby script/server WORKS! @Doon you rule. Thank you for your infinite n00b-friendly patience :D!

Comment: One last thing: installing mysql 2.8.1...
Error running 'GEM_HOME='/Users/leonardodarioperna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302' GEM_PATH='/Users/leonardodarioperna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302'  gem install mysql -v2.8.1    ', please read /Users/leonardodarioperna/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gem.install.log
mysql 2.8.1 failed to install ( output logged to: /Users/leonardodarioperna/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gem.install.log )
|| gem.install.log = http://pastebin.com/JwR0bhnp

Comment: Well the problem is you are using mysql and not postgresql :)  Do you have mysql server installed? and does the configure line for the mysql  gem look correct. that pastebin doesn't appear to point to the correct log.  But my guess is that you either don't have the server or the client libs installed for mysql..

Comment: Some people got similar issues ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357997/snow-leopard-ruby-1-9-1-mysql-gem-huge-problems

Comment: how did you install mysql?  I am seeing that the gem will fail if you installed mysql using the DMG  (As it is missing libraries.)  Try installing mysql from macports (mysql5 mysql5-server)  which will fill in the missing depends and should make the gem work..

Answer (score 0):

The last two `PATH=` lines appear to be the problem. There's a Ruby in your `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/local/bin` directory and it's taking precedence over the system-installed one. I'm not sure why migrating to Snow Leopard would trigger this, since I don't believe it adds those lines to the file.

Doon's recommendation of [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) is not necessary, but it is a really handy tool.

Comment: My guess is that pre snow leopard, OP had upgraded system ruby using gem update --system. Upgrade to snow leopard replaces the system ruby.  My guess is gem path and the like are getting all messed up  due the /usr/bin/rails file calling the ruby in system frameworks.  When I upgraded to snow leopard I did a clean install and then migrated all my data over, rebuilt the dev environment (This was pre -rvm)  now that I am using RVM. I leave the system ruby alone.

Comment: @Leonardo Dario Perna: Remove the last two PATH= lines, like I said.

Comment: Thanks, I've commented the last two PATH= lines but nothing changed :(