# Mysql Snow leopard issue

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Just installed snow leopard and Xcode, i downloaded version 5.1.38 from the mysql website and installed it, then i ran **sudo gem uninstall mysql** and when i try to gem install mysql as below i get a documentation error, also when i try to run mysql by simply typing **mysql** into terminal i get **-bash: mysql: command not found**. When i try to connect via MySql Administrator (gui) and also through my ruby on rails app i get   **Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock**. Any suggestions?

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config


Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
```

Comment: the problem was that the old MySQL was still running, go into system preferences >> mysql and "stop mysql server" once done, perform steps in the post below, and start the mysql server through system preferences. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me and my team member successfully following steps from http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/30/upgrading-to-snow-leopard

but rather than update MacPort, We re-install it from dmg file. The Rubygems by get it update manually

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
```

Answer (score 0):

Snow Leopard screws up Mac Ports and MySQL. There's another SO question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found my answer here:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?116,359591,359591#msg-359591

Make sure you read all the post.

The author says specifically:

"So what you're looking for here is not a universal, "right instruction" to install the mysql gem; what we need is universal instruction to build the right instruction for our particular gem and MySQL installation."

For me the right solution was:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql --no-rdoc --no-ri -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```