# Cannot start mysql on mac

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails, MySQL and Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard)

I have installed mysql recently on mac OSx 10.6 snow leopard but I am not able to start it from the control pane. When I click on start SQL Server ,the status does not change. Please help.

Comment: Seriously, there's so much content on SO and on the web about this...