# Rails-MySQL Error - uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard

Trying to get a Rails app running on Snow Leopard.

- Downloaded mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg and ran installer
- Ruby 1.8.7 (Default OS X version)
- Rails 2.3.5

When I attempt to run "rake db:migrate" I get

- rake aborted!
- uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

Yes I know this has been asked before. I have already reviewed the following links and followed the steps included in them and the result is the same each time.

- [Rails, MySQL and Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard)
- http://techliberty.blogspot.com/2009/12/dealing-with-rake-aborted-uninitialized.html
- http://www.schmidp.com/2009/06/14/rubyrails-and-mysql-on-snow-leopard-10a380/

Prior to the following commands I run "sudo gem uninstall mysql" followed by "sudo gem clean mysql" based on the above links:

- sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
- sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

It is still failing. I am just flumoxed and would greatly appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not had the experience myself and I'm using Snow Leopard, RVM and rails 2.3.5 to 3.0.3, but found another view which deals with the uninstall and reinstall via :

`export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" ;sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri  -v=2.7 mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql  --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

For more details see the posting at:  http://accidentaltechnologist.com/apple/fixing-uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres-error-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: He shoots! He scores!... The root issue being that the 2.8.x MySQL Gem seems to not work on Snow Leopard but 2.7 works just find. Thank you, thank you, thank you! Note - In order to make this work I also had to add "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/" to my .bash_login file per [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve which discusses the other error I got after downgrading to 2.7. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For **El Capitan** you don't need to uninstall / install.

Just found your `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` file. Location will depent on how you installed mysql

```
locate libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Once you have the path create a symb link as:

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql-5.5.20-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

You have two change first param according to your dynamic library location (use the first command).

On El Capitan the link should be to `/usr/local/lib`. On previous versions link was to `/usr/lib/`

Comment: This worked for me on El Capitan with MySQL 5.7.18, only it was `libmysqlclient.20.dylib` not `18`.