# installing Webistrano RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate fails on Mac OS 10.6.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rake, capistrano, webistrano

I've been trying to install Webistrano. I have installed all the dependencies required for it, including Capistrano, as described on the github wiki: https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/wiki/Installation. I have googled these error messages and have not found any helpful info.

When running RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate I get the following error messages:

SUDO

```
webistrano username$ sudo RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate 
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rake (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1276:in `gem'
    from /Users/u sername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:18:in `<main>'
```

No SUDO

```
webistrano username$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate 
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The MysqlRes issue has been asked and solved many times here. Short answer is you need to [reinstall the gem with custom settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915461/rails-mysql-error-uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres).

Comment: I wish I could say this is my problem, but I have already try to un-install and re-install mysql gem with the custom settings with little success (this is for 2.8.1). when trying to install 2.7 I get: make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1