# Rails server won't start (LoadError) mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick, mysql2

I'm kind of a newbie at rails, I have to make a small rails project for school, but somehow I can't even get my server to run, really promising start, hope someone can help me out ;-).

When I try to start my rails server, it gives me a load error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/sanderdeclerck1/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I'm running rails 3.0.8, and ruby 1.8.7

Anyone got any suggestion?

edit: forgot to mention I'm on OS X 10.6.7

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're on OS X, so therefore you should **install MySQL first** before actually loading the mysql Gem.

Two options:

1. Follow [this guide here](http://blog.devinterface.com/2010/09/how-to-install-mysql-and-rails-on-osx-snow-leopard/) or [this slightly older guide](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-mongrel-mysql-osx/) on how to set everything up (MySQL, Ruby and Rails). It should actually be enough if you install MySQL from the official website, but it involves a bit of fiddling around before from my experience.
2. You can also install MySQL through [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew). Here's a [guide](https://gist.github.com/993344) for that. Note that you have to manually start it with

   ```
   launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
   ```

Comment: Oh, okay *then* that's a slightly different problem. Are you sure it's running? I've kinda seen the same error when not loading it with `launchctl`

Comment: Ye, I can access it using mysql workbench, so it's definitely running

Comment: Hm. Maybe [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serve) helps. Or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard) one.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the MySQL server not running.  It's failing to load the shared object (or the dylib in Mac terms), presumably because it's not at a known location (or not installed at all).

Comment: @d11wtq Yeah, I'd just suggest to install again.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your `~/.profile`. If your mysql install is not in `/usr/local` you will have to change that path.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ubuntu try to install `apt-get install ruby-dev libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev` package

Answer (score 0):

How did you install MySQL?  You might need to specify `--with-lib` or `--with-mysql-dir` when installing the MySQL gem.

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include'
```

Answer (score 0):

you might just need to reinstall the mysql2 gem.

first you should find your mysql_config.
you can do this by issuing:

```
sudo find /usr/local -name mysql_config
```

then install the gem with

```
(sudo) gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=RESULT_FROM_ABOVE
```

this should give you a gem that is configured with your mysql installation.
Hope that helps.