# Connecting MySQL with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to connect to MySQL using Ruby, and been getting following issue:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin10.0/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin10.0/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap

I am using 'ruby-mysql' gem, and run x86_64 bit MySQL as advised here `http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/30/upgrading-to-snow-leopard`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: When you post a question, you should include an actual answerable question rather than simply describing a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails, MySQL and Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard) One of the answerers of this question had your problem (is there a way to link to an answer?)

He solved it this way:

```
sudo rm -f /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin10.0/mysql.bundle
```

Haven't tried it myself, though.