# Rails Not Connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get my database to connect and interact properly with my SQL Database. When I type...

rake db:schema:dump

I get........

```
simple_cms gregpfeffer$ rake db:schema:dump
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I edited my database.yml to now read...

```
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms      
  password: XXXXXXXXXX
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Any idea whats going on here? I have both the mySQL and mySQL2 gem installed, not sure if that helps.

Thanks so much!
Greg Pfeffer

Comment: Check:
1. if you can connect with the db from command line with this credentials and have access to the database

2. Did you put the gem in Gemfile and installed it in the app with bundle install

3. Here was similar problem on mac: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard/1241484#1241484

Comment: I can access mySQL through my command line, yes.

Comment: Not sure about 2....I'm trying to install this as part of the Lynda.com essentials tutorial so I'm not 100% understanding 2. can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Try using mysql2 as adapter. It seems you are using the mysql2 gem.

```
  adapter: mysql2
```

Comment: Silvio, can you please clarify? When should I use the call adapter : mysql2 ?

Comment: @beck03076 nope can still cant get it to work after changing adapter to mysql1