# Trying to setup radiant cms on osx

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, radiant

I am attempting to install radiant cms, when I try and run bundle exec rake db:bootstrap I get the following output. Now I chose mysql as my database but Im not sure if it is setup properly or not to connect. Sorry If it sounds like I dont know what Im talking about this is still somewhat new to me.

```
Gem.source_index called from /Users/anderskitson/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
/Users/anderskitson/Sites/Bray Jorstad/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:bootstrap => db:initialize => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

1. install rvm bash -s stable < <(curl -s
   https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
2. setup rvm echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source
   "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bash_profile source ~/.bash_profile
3. download & install Xcode open
   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg
   open ~/Downloads/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg open "/Volumes/Install
   Xcode/InstallXcodeLion.pkg"
4. install ruby & rubygems rvm install 1.9.3 # or 1.9.2 or 1.8.7
5. setup an isolated environment for your project rvm use --create
   1.9.3@project-name
6. install radiant gem install radiant --pre --no-ri --no-rdoc #
   installs Radiant 1.0 RC4
7. create a new radiant project radiant ~/project-name cd
   ~/project-name bundle install bundle exec rake db:bootstrap
8. install optional clipped dependencies brew install ghostscript
   imagemagick # or port install ... brew install --use-gcc ffmpeg  #
   or port install ffmpeg
9. start your new radiant app bundle exec script/server

Courtesy of:

https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Installing-on-Mac-OS-X

I did this today (22/05/13) in OSX (10.7.5) and everything worked fine. Just don't fiddle with your gem file. Keep your database as sqlite3 when developing, or at least until you get everything working.

Good luck!

Comment: A couple of things I am using rbenv and dont want to install rvm because of comflicts between rbenv and rvm. However I have seem to do everything in the instruction sup until 7. which is where i get the error above.